# Is it OK to reference a Web API project from an ASP.Net Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, reference, asp.net-core-webapi

Note that I've never done this before until now as I've never had a need to.

I am trying to leverage an existing Asp.net core Web API project. 
I have an Asp.net core project which is essentially referencing the Web API project in the hopes of "inheriting" all the implemented API's.

Structure:

> "ASP.Net Core Project" has as reference to "ASP.Net Web API Project"

Seems like this works for the most part. Unfortunately i see this working intermittently. Specifically the failures are occurring with the "inherited" API's. Calls to the referenced API's are failing (again intermittently), and thus returning a 404 (rather than the JSON API response).

**Question**

> So it seems there is nothing inherently wrong with this approach (as @Arash has commented/confirmed). So wondering what could be the cause of this intermittent issue?

**Updates**

I am now verifying using Postman to easily verify the API's. I can confirm that the API's that i have in the Asp.Net Core Project is working. But the API's from the "inherited" Web API Project are not working.

Again, to paraphrase: Can a Web API project be referenced as a DLL and expect to have those API's consumable?

Comment: 1) why would a Web API have Razor components? It shouldn't be providing a GUI. And anyway if you have components you want to share between the two projects, the normal, modern way to do that would be to put those bits into a 3rd project, publish that as a Nuget package and install the resulting package into both projects. That way you don't end up with strange dependencies between otherwise unrelated projects, and you won't get "step change" issues where if you upgrade one you have to upgrade the other one simultaneously. Referencing isn't wrong per se, but this sounds like an odd case for it

Comment: 2) "Calls to Project A API's are failing..." How are you calling them exactly? We can't really fix code we can't see.  Also "intermittently"...unless you have something physical / semi-phyiscal like network issues, computers don't randomly fail for no reason. You need to find out what the pattern of behaviour is.

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with referencing one project (of any kind) in another. But as far as why you're getting intermittent errors, you probably need to provide some more details and specifics.